# Abbreviation for Estimated

Tags: abbreviations

What is the correct abbreviation for the word estimated? (not "estimated time of arrival", just the single word)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but... If abbreviating, I think I'd be more likely to use appx. (approximately). Or perhaps the tilde (~) character, which is also commonly used as a prefix to indicate an approximate number. ("transit time is ~10 min.")

Answer (score 7):

The correct abbreviation is *"est."*

> est. transit time is 10 min.

Comment: Though if it was about transit time, I'd probably use ETA :)

Comment: @JonHanna def. :)

Comment: In what way isn't this question general reference?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Did I say it wasn't? I simply answered it instead of flagging it.

Comment: 'If we accept the axiom that trivial questions are bad for the site, then the proper response to a general reference question is: Don't answer!' [@Martha; meta]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth noted. I'll abstain/flag in the future.

Comment: I've edited so I can reverse my vote. Finding Martha's gem was a bonus. I suppose there will come a time when there's a bun-fight about whether a certain question _is_ genref.